# rotation and translation of object opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

So i m working with opencv to find an object inside an image i have scene image and the object image i could detect the object with template matching but i need to give a rotation tolerance which is not avaible with template matching i m going to use feature 2D to detect features with findhomography and decomposehomography so i can get the translation and rotation but i want to understand how can i find decomposehomography parametre K – The input intrinsic camera calibration matrix.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so I will post it
first of all the use of feature desciption algorithm is needed i choosed to work with SURF algorithm
after finding the object and the scene keypoints you need to find the homography matrix with findhomography after that you can calculate the angle using this code

```
    float a = homography.at<double>(0, 0);
    float b = homography.at<double>(0, 1);
    float theta = atan2(b, a) * (180 / M_PI);
    cout << theta;
```

for the translation after finding the homography matrix you can find the location of the object in the image and compare the initial position with the position found

```
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    obj_corners[0] = Point2f(0, 0);
    obj_corners[1] = Point2f((float)patch.cols, 0);
    obj_corners[2] = Point2f((float)patch.cols, (float)patch.rows);
    obj_corners[3] = Point2f(0, (float)patch.rows);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    //it will return the scene_corners 
    //these corners are the location of the patch in the master
    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, homography);
```

the scene_corners contains the coordination of the object in the image